# assuming the Old Testament YHWH could not create angels, how would He recruit them?

Tags: religion, ancient-history, angels

I mean to tell a story set during the time of the Book of Genesis, leading up to the destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah. YVVH (one of many regional gods) builds more power, as part of a plan to accumulate dominance over the middle east. (eventually, of course, he gets it.) I want to assume that YHWH cannot simply create them. also, I want to present a world without the Christian or Islamic additions to mythology, so he could not, just say, recruit djinn. (based on what I have looked up, it seems that the idea of djinns originated as a way to explain away revival gods to Allah.) the Persians regarded daevas as evil and I conceive of the devas as too far to the east. YHVH has no followers there and therefore can't travel there.

has anyone any creative ideas as to how he could have recruited angels?

Comment: Please refer to the [help] regarding our standards for on-topic questions.

Comment: Our [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid." Without providing any criteria by which you will judge a best answer, this question becomes off-topic as opinion-based. In this regard, we're a bit different from the rest of Stack Exchange. It's as much your opinion as ours. Your selection of a best answer is opinion-based because you appear to be fishing for ideas rather than trying to find a single, best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You've already set up a world in which multiple regional gods are competing with each other for power. Why not take the easy path: assume there are a host of minor 'gods', too weak to establish power or find followers of their own, and thus willing to become 'angels' (lieutenants or foot soldiers) for one of the major gods who has *real* power. A *'better to serve in heaven than be a complete failure'* kind of thing.

It's a bit like the Gods in [Lankhmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lankhmar) (as opposed to the gods *of* Lankhmar), who are constantly vying for worshipers, moving up and down the Avenue of the Gods as they gain and lose followers.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Modify** something that exists or that he can create into an angel.  I cannot forge an iron knife.  But I can sharpen something make of iron.  Maybe the angels are beings which have been modified or uplifted by Y.
2. **Buy them.**  If other entities have angels maybe Y could purchase or steal or trade with those entities.
3. **Attract them.**   How to attract the spirits of fallen baseball greats?  How to attract birds for me to view?   Build a place where they want to be.  Perhaps Y makes a place where angels want to be, and they arrive.
4. **Abduct them.**  Angels are taken against their will, like capturing Pokemon.
5. **He is them.** Perhaps Y splits off portions of himself and names these avatars as angels.
6. **They just show up.**  This is my favorite.  The angels choose to come and it is not clear why.  They are beings whose motives are hard to understand and they are not forthcoming.  It is not clear to Y what they get out of the deal.  But they showed up, and he is glad they did.
7. Methods 1 thru 6.  One angel each way.